# Login issues with domain.com

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I created a new website over a year ago through domain.com. It is managed on Wordpress, but each time I try to log in to the site it takes me to an old site of mine. I can't get anything from either of these companies. Can someone assist?

Thanks,
Ilanna

I have tried to reach help several times. No answer.

Comment: Can you give more information about your issue? It is hard to know what is the actual issue ... When you are logged out, is your site good ?

Comment: Maybe try with different browser. If this problem is happening in Chrome, try again in Edge or Firefox.